# Jquery Ajax pass value but doesnot display in div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fix this issues from last two days but :(

Now I have a index.php page where I am displaying all the data of adds from database.
this is my index page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var overlayclass = $("<div id='overlayclass'></div>");
     //pagination starts
     $("#pagination li:first")
     .css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 10px'});
     $("#page").load("Controller/pagination_data_all_adds.php?page=1");
    //Pagination Click
    $("#pagination li").click(function(){
 //CSS Styles
    $("#pagination li")
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
    .css({'border' : 'none'});
    $(this)
    .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 10px'})
    .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});
//Loading Data
   var pageNum = this.id;
     $("#page").load("Controller/pagination_data_all_adds.php?page=" + pageNum);
     });
//pagination ends                 
//for closing the div
   $(".close").click(function () {
    $(".divpopup").hide();
    overlayclass.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
   });
//for close image
   $(".x").click(function () {
   $(".divpopup").hide();
   overlayclass.appendTo(document.body).remove();
   return false;
 });
//onclick on button display div and overlay with button value and post the value to the index   page where I can use it to select the specific adds data from database
$(':submit').live('click',function () {
var id = $(this).val();
overlayclass.show();
overlayclass.appendTo(document.body);
$(".divpopup").show('slow');
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php',
data:'button=' + $(this).val(),
dataType: 'json',
succss: function(data)
{
$('.divpopup').html('');
alert(data);
$('.divpopup').append('button:'+data);
}
});
return false;
});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="divpopup">
<div class="divcontent">
<img src="http://www.catalyst-gc.com/images/icon_close_window.jpg" alt="icon_close_window" 
class="x" id="imgclose" />

<div class="detail_data">

<?php

print "<h1>".$button."</h1>";

?>

</div>

<a href="" class="close">Close</a>

</div>

</div>


<div id="page"></div>

<ul id="pagination">

<?php

//Pagination Numbers

for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++)

{

echo '<li id="'.$i.'"-->'.$i.'';
}

?>

</ul>

<!--Pagging display ends -->

</body>

</html>
```

This is my pagination_data_all_adds page which will be load through jQquery load function in index page. inside page div. and the button which is inside table will be click to display the popupdiv with id of adds and than I will use it to display the rest of the data.

```
<?php include_once('dbconn.php');
$per_page = 6;
if($_GET)  
{  
$page=$_GET['page'];  
}  

$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;  
$sql = "select * from adds order by add_id limit $start,$per_page";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
echo "<table cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th>Advertise</th>";
echo "<th>Title</th>";
//echo "<th>Description</th>";
echo "<th>Price</th>";
echo "</thead>";
while ($adds = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr class='even'>";
$image_link = $adds["image"];
echo "<td><img class='image' src=adds_images/".$image_link."></td>";
echo "<td><b>".$adds["add_type"] . "</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>".$adds["add_title"] ."</b></td>";
echo "<td><b>".$adds["add_price"] ."</b></td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<form method='post' action=''>"
echo "<button class='button' value='".$adds['add_id']."' type='submit'>Detail!</button>";
echo "</form>";
echo"</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
}
 echo "</table>";?>
```

Now the problem is when I click on the button which is page div it display nothing but when I look at Firebug response it shows there. It does not display when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataType in ajax call is `json`.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'index.php',
data:'button=' + $(this).val(),
dataType: 'json', <--------------------------------- JSON
```

But you are returning `html`.

```
echo "<table cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th>Advertise</th>";
..........................
..........................
```

Hence your call is actually **failing** (Which you could have spotted had you used `fail`).

So answer is return `json` or change data type.

---

## N.B.

LOTS AND LOTS OF deprecated function. use `.on` instead of `live`. use `.done` instead of `success`. use `mysqli/pdo` instead of `mysql`.

```
    if($_GET)  
{  
$page=$_GET['page'];  
}
```

You need to use `isset` or `empty` that too on approriate index. `$_GET` is always set. So checking its existance is futile. You need to check the index. i.e.

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
```

Comment: actually what iam trying to do is on the index page iam getting all the records from database and than using jquery pagination. and pagination data php page contains table which will display only 6 records. after index page is load with all the records. there is detail button, and when click the button it should display a popup div which is inside index page , and when index page load popup div is disable and when i click detail button it should appear with the id and select row record. Iam new to jquery ajax dont know much yet

Comment: your solution is, return json data from php. otherwise it won't show and ajax call will **fail**. or else, remove the dataType and let jquery handle it.

Answer (score 0):

again echoing what @itachi has said, pass json data from your php. your js script is waiting for json object yet you passing html file. 
to use your code the way it is comment out this line from your JavaScript //dataType: 'json',.
i would also encourage you to use jquery dataTables to save time. take a look at it [here](http://datatables.net/)